# SQL Insert, Update can't see existing record and instead it duplicate the founded one

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a strange situation where I am checking to insert or update if record exist by array from a loop through html table rows. If I fill 1st first record and leave the second empty, it will insert it to the db but will not accept any inserting later to the second row, instead it will duplicate the 1st row record. interchangablly, If I fill the the second row first. If I fill both of them @ the begining it will insert them both but for any change later it will not recognize (Not found) the second record and it will duplicate the first record?

[image]

below is the code:

```
#region //if exist update else insert inserting code
//Response.Write("<script>alert('InputDate = " + stringList2[6] + 
//" and Dept= " + stringList2[7] + " and DeptType= " + stringList2[8] + 
//" and DeptSubType= " + stringList2[9] + "')</script>");
con.Open();
//cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM MainDailyData WHERE Dept= '" + stringList2[7] + 
//    "' and DeptType = '" + stringList2[8] + "' and DeptSubType= '" + stringList2[9] + "'", con);
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM MainDailyData WHERE Dept= @dpt and DeptType = @dptType and DeptSubType= @DptSbType", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dpt", stringList2[7]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dptType", stringList2[8]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DptSbType", stringList2[9]);

bool fRecordExists = false;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
{
fRecordExists = true;
}
dr.Close();
dr.Dispose();
if (fRecordExists)
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('Found,Update')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MainDailyData SET Product1 = @Prod1, Product2 = @Prod2, Product3 = @Prod3, Product4 = @Prod4, Product5 = @Prod5, Product6 = @Prod6, InputDate = @InDate, Dept = @Dpt, DeptType = @DptType, DeptSubType = @DptSubType", con);
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
myda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('not Found,Insert')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MainDailyData (Product1,Product2,Product3,Product4,Product5,Product6,InputDate,Dept,DeptType,DeptSubType) VALUES(@Prod1,@Prod2,@Prod3,@Prod4,@Prod5,@Prod6,@InDate,@Dpt,@DptType,@DptSubType)", con);
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
myda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
#endregion
```

My apology if this considered a duplication thread but my previous question was different and solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, your update command misses the Where clause and this is strange.  This looks to be the cause of the issue, at least I do not see other obvious problems in your code.  How do you identify which row to update?

Also, there is no need to call the DataReader.Dispose and DataReader.Close method subsequently.  The DataReader.Dispose method calls Close itself.

Comment: you are great maaan..silly mistake costed me alot of time.thanks again brother.